# Reportlab - Keep last row of first table and the second table together

Tags: python, split, reportlab, platypus

I have two tables, a invoice table with items of the invoice and a table with the invoice total.

I want both tables to stay together, and when they don't fit on one page, the first table should split, but the last row of the first table should stay by the second table.

Both tables have a different number of columns and a different styling.

Is that possible?

Answer (score -1):

to split the first table and merge it with the next one you can try this

```
var firstTable=$("#firstTable");
var secondTable=$("#secondTable");
var lastRowFirstTable=firstTable.find("tbody tr:last-child").html();
secondTable.find("tbody").prepend(lastRowFirstTable);
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that the two tables have a different number of columns and accordingly also a different styling. I assume that I can not simply hang a row from the one table into the other one, right?

Comment: You definitely can, but that may look like something is missing.
If it is the above case then you can't join the two tables.

I hope my answer was helpful to you, so, you may upvote my answer.

Comment: The question is about Python code, but your answer is not.